# Grouping mutually exclusive IDs in a dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I am working on a project, where my task is to identify groups, who are connected through either of 4 IDs. For example:

[image]

In this case, the first element is one group, since none of its IDs match with any other IDs in the list. The second and the third elements create a second group, since at least one of their IDs are matching.

My original idea was to create unique IDs through concatenating the 4 IDs, then compare them with the values already present in the dict and if there is at least a partial match, append it to the respective key-value pair, otherwise update the dict with a new key-value pair, including the respective unique ID. The code:

```
import pandas as pd
d = {"ID_1" : [7900584388, 7993236875, 7993236875],
     "ID_2" : ["CML00500006425034016", "CML00500006405019019", 
               "CML00500006405019025"],
     "ID_3" : [2010007625, 2010007633, 2010007633],
     "ID_4" : [1016008787, 1016008794, 1016008794]}
df = pd.DataFrame(d, dtype = str).dropna()
group_dict = {"foo":["1_1_1_1"]}
df["UID"] = df["ID_1"] + "_" + df["ID_2"] + "_" + df["ID_3"] + "_" + df["ID_4"]
UID = list(df["UID"])

for i in UID:
    i_split = i.split("_")
    for k, v in group_dict.items():
        x = 0
        c = 0
        for d in v:
            d_split = d.split("_")
            print(d_split)
            if len(set(i_split) & set(d_split)) > 0:
                x += 1
        if x > 0:
            group_dict[k].append(i)
        else:
            group_dict.update({c:[i]})
            c += 1
```

The desired outcome based on the three-element example would be this for group_dict:

```
{'foo': ['1_1_1_1'], 0: ['7900584388_CML00500006425034016_2010007625_1016008787'], 1: ['7993236875_CML00500006405019019_2010007633_1016008794', '7993236875_CML00500006405019025_2010007633_1016008794']}
```

Unfortunately, I get a RuntimeError with this solution, since the dictionary size changes during iteration. Could you recommend me, how to make this code work, or perhaps an alternative approach to the grouping issue? Thank you for the feedbacks in advance!

Comment: before anyone can help you, would you please post the DataFrame as code, so users can paste it into their IDE

Comment: I agree with aws_apprentice. I think you've done a good job of making a pretty good question already, especially since you added your desired outcome in code. But the other part we need to test any solution is the input in code.

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up, edited the post with the correct input, same three-elements, as seen in the example spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can collect the related indexes in a set:

```
s=set()                                                                                                              
for col in ["ID_1","ID_2","ID_3","ID_4"]: 
     s|= { tuple(idxs) for key,idxs in df.groupby(col).groups.items() }

{(0,), (1,), (1, 2), (2,)}
```

You can do anything with it, e.g:

```
for e in s: 
      if len(e)>1: 
         print( df.loc[list(e)] ) 

         ID_1                  ID_2        ID_3        ID_4
1  7993236875  CML00500006405019019  2010007633  1016008794
2  7993236875  CML00500006405019025  2010007633  1016008794
```

Comment: Thank you! Can I ask, why is there a bitwise operator before the equal sign? Haven't used it beforehand, and I would like to understand its purpose.

Comment: It is in place 'or', as +=, *=, etc.

Comment: In this case this is a set operator, 'union'. Otherwise: s= s.union(s2)